Sublime text on a usb driver, how do i set up on standalone gcc compiler?
I am trying to prepare a usb drive for use at school. I'll be compiling and running school work. I downloaded a portable version of Sublime Text
https://www.sublimetext.com/download
and the standalone version of GCC
https://winlibs.com/
Now, this is my setting for compiling on g++ on my linux and windows laptops.
However, when I try to compile on my usb stick sublimetext,  it says "gcc" is not in the path. I do have the standalone version of mingw on the same usb stick.
Is it possible to point the g++ in my compile setting to the gcc on my usbstick?
Thanks!
{
    "shell_cmd": "g++ \"${file}\" -o \"${file_path}/${file_base_name}\"",
    "file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
    "working_dir": "${file_path}",
    "selector": "source.c, source.c++",

    "variants":
    [
        {
            "name": "Run",
            "shell_cmd": "g++ \"${file}\" -o \"${file_path}/${file_base_name}\" && \"${file_path}/${file_base_name}\""
        }
    ]
}


I used to have such problems, theses are some possible turnarounds:

Put the MiNGW, or any other compiler, inside
the sublime text directory so you can access the
g++ relatively as: MiNGW/bin/g++

Create a cmd.exe instance and add gcc to path before
running sublime text (you could create a special
bat file for that)

In the worst case, you will need to enter the full path
to gcc, or g++ and edit it as required.


